# How can I connect two databse in single console application

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I have created one console application and connected with database which is in SSMS (SQL Server). I have implemented profiling in this application. But I have created a `.sdf` file (SQL Server CE database) to store profiling related records using C# code. This `.sdf` file is located in my application's bin folder.

How can I connect both of the databases with my application to save/insert profiler data in `.sdf` file?

Comment: Check this article http://erikej.blogspot.sk/2008/10/accessing-sql-compact-from-sql-server.html

Comment: @VDohnal: Thank you! But do not you have other option? Unable to understand this article. It is about to get data from the table. My problem is only connection related. Because application is alresdy connected with one database. How can I connect CE database to insert records?

Comment: It is not completely clear to me what you ask. If you need to connect to both databases just from your app, you just make 2 separate connections. You then cannot join tables from either database with one query though.  But in a C# app there is certainly no problem to connect to severeal databases. You will need to include parts of your code to make your problem more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two different SQLConnection instances at the run-time , one for writing and other one for reading. Just create separate variable.